# Remove added control with Javascript in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to removed the added controls. Here's the mark-up that adds upload controls to the page:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Multi File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p id="upload-area">
   <input id="File1" type="file" runat="server" size="60" />
</p>

<input id="AddFile" type="button" value="Add file" onclick="addFileUploadBox()" />
<br />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<p><asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Upload Now" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" /></p>
<span id="Span1" runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function addFileUploadBox()
{
    if (!document.getElementById || !document.createElement)
        return false;

    var uploadArea = document.getElementById ("upload-area");

    if (!uploadArea)
        return;

    var newLine = document.createElement ("br");
    uploadArea.appendChild (newLine);

    var newUploadBox = document.createElement ("input");

    // Set up the new input for file uploads
    newUploadBox.type = "file";
    newUploadBox.size = "60";

    // The new box needs a name and an ID
    if (!addFileUploadBox.lastAssignedId)
        addFileUploadBox.lastAssignedId = 100;

    newUploadBox.setAttribute ("id", "dynamic" + addFileUploadBox.lastAssignedId);
    newUploadBox.setAttribute ("name", "dynamic:" + addFileUploadBox.lastAssignedId);
    uploadArea.appendChild (newUploadBox);
    addFileUploadBox.lastAssignedId++;
}
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank.

Answer (score 1):

try parent.removeChild(element);

The following site seems to answer what you are looking for:
http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-remove-elements-reprise/